# Windows Command Prompts 'systeminfo' command equivalent on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, windows, system-information

With Windows' command prompt, I can get a simplified system hardware overview through `systeminfo` command. On Ubuntu I can get a lot of non GUI commands with lots of info plus verbose details. There are some GUI tools like `sysinfo`. But I can't find a non-GUI one. So, can I get a simplified non-verbose non-GUI system information summary through terminal on Ubuntu?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us exactly what system information you are looking for. You need to list what you want to see.

Answer (score 2):

Try `inxi`:

```
$ inxi
CPU: 6-Core Intel Core i7-8700K (-MT MCP-) speed/min/max: 800/800/4700 MHz 
Kernel: 5.4.0-52-generic x86_64 Up: 7h 17m Mem: 12886.2/32061.5 MiB (40.2%) 
Storage: 6.37 TiB (35.2% used) Procs: 374 Shell: bash 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38
```

For more verbose output

```
inxi -F
```

---

Alternative: `neofetch`;

```
$ neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               user@PC 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ---------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: MS-7B45 2.0 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.4.0-52-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 7 hours, 20 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 3626 (dpkg), 15 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.0.17 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 2560x1440 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Adwaita 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: tilix 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: Intel i7-8700K (12) @ 4.700GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 10264MiB / 32061MiB 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

Both installable via `apt`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not using Windows, so I'm not sure what can `systeminfo` do, but here are few commands based on screenshots I googled.

Basic system information: `hostnamectl`

```
$ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: vtrefny-Standard-PC-Q35-ICH9-2009
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: 07bb5131d4b54404aedd3c859da18c05
           Boot ID: 6bf5dda3c6f3434ea4a249bd34cb0b30
    Virtualization: kvm
  Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-48-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

CPU information: `lscpu`

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          2
On-line CPU(s) list:             0,1
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              1
Socket(s):                       2
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           94
Model name:                      Intel Core Processor (Skylake, IBRS)
Stepping:                        3
CPU MHz:                         2111.996
BogoMIPS:                        4223.99
Virtualization:                  VT-x
Hypervisor vendor:               KVM
```

Memory information: `lsmem`

```
$ lsmem
RANGE                                 SIZE  STATE REMOVABLE BLOCK
0x0000000000000000-0x000000007fffffff   2G online       yes  0-15
0x0000000100000000-0x000000017fffffff   2G online       yes 32-47

Memory block size:       128M
Total online memory:       4G
Total offline memory:      0B
```

Other tools:

- `lsusb`: devices connected to USB
- `lspci`: PCI devices
- `lshw`: detailed hardware info
- `/proc/cpuinfo` (file): detailed CPU information
- `lsblk`: list of block devices
- `df -h`: mounted filesystem with size and free space

There is of course more. Not sure if there is a one tool that can print all the information, but the tools I mentioned are installed by default and in Linux/Unix we usually have one tool for one thing (see [Unix Philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy)).